# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph despite using tabular in wizard

Tags: tables, errors, badness

I've read the other topics on this but I really cannot understand why I'm getting it in my case when it has been made by the wizard rather than by hand.
I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{eg}{Example}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{4.}]
\end{itemize}
Let $A=[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.\\
\\
\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
space $X$ & $A^o$ & $\overline{A}$ & $\partial A$ & Is $A$ open? & Is $A$ closed? \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\varnothing$ & $[0,1]$ & $[0,1]$ & No & No \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ & $A$ & $A$ & $\varnothing$ & Yes & Yes \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} \\
\\
For $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus A} = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{R} = [0,1]$.\\
For $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $\partial A = A \cap ((\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})_{<0} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})_{>1}) = \varnothing$.

\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{5.}]
\end{itemize}
Proofs are in the notes.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a compilable version of your code, not just fragments. By the way: Perhaps you should use `\begin{enumerate} \item ...\end{enumerate}` instead of `\item[\textbf{4.}]` etc.

Comment: I hope the edit provided enough, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: the example produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`  you are missing an environment.

Comment: Please post an example that produces the underfull hbox warning in your question. (you can delete all parts of the example unrelated to that.)

Comment: Although I just made an edit, I was too slow so just rolled it back to your version.

Comment: Sorry I should have left you longer to edit, I just dropped it in as I made the edits while making the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underfull hbox warnings are due to

```
\\
\\
```

as this forces two linebreaks with nothing in between so the resulting line is "under full" and infinitely bad (badness 10000 being as bad as TeX can report).

You should avoid all use of `\\` outside its use to end table rows.

This has no warnings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{eg}{Example}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\section{}
Let $A=[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
space $X$ & $A^o$ & $\overline{A}$ & $\partial A$ & Is $A$ open? & Is $A$ closed? \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\varnothing$ & $[0,1]$ & $[0,1]$ & No & No \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ & $A$ & $A$ & $\varnothing$ & Yes & Yes \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

For $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R} \setminus A} = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{R} = [0,1]$.\\
For $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $\partial A = A \cap ((\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})_{<0} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})_{>1}) = \varnothing$.

\section{}
Proofs are in the notes.

\end{document}
```